# Deal with unsupported(?) characters in file names

Tags: python-2.7, shutil

This is the error:

```
>>>File found: E:\Other\xristopoulos-laptop\PHOTO\quotes\????? t?t??.png

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zarkopafilis\Desktop\fileExtractor.py", line 39, in <module>
shutil.copy2(x , target)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'E:\\Other\\xristopoulos-laptop\\PHOTO\\quotes\\????? t?t??.png'
```

I am using shutil.copy2(src , dest) to copy some files from one directory to another. How do I face these errors? The unsupported characters are greek

Comment: What codec did you use to produce the filename? Have you tried passing in a *Unicode* object instead?

Comment: I've not tried to pass in a unicode object.

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16 for filenames. Your console is probably responsible for the `?` replacements for characters it cannot decode though. Can you show us your code on how you are producing these filenames?

Comment: I fixed it by adding unicode(x)